# 'System::String ^' to 'LPCWSTR'

Tags: .net, winapi, visual-c++, clr

I want to convert `System::String ^` to `LPCWSTR`.

for

```
FindFirstFile(LPCWSTR,WIN32_FIND_DATA);
```

Please help.

Comment: m using vc++ .. just lost the code track, so .. need time to use the answers.

Answer (score 26):

The easiest way to do this in C++/CLI is to use `pin_ptr`:

```
#include <vcclr.h>

void CallFindFirstFile(System::String^ s)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wname = PtrToStringChars(s);
    FindFirstFile(wname, &data);
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that the `wname` points to the actual character data in `s`, not a copy thereof, which can make it more efficient than other marshaling solutions. (`const` hints at that)

Answer (score 11):

To convert a System::String ot LPCWSTR in C++/CLI you can you use the [Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi.aspx) function to convert managed strings to unmanaged strings.

```
System::String ^str = "Hello World";

IntPtr ptr = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(str);

HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile((LPCSTR)ptr.ToPointer(), data);

System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::FreeHGlobal(ptr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use P/Invoke. Check this link: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/FindFirstFile.html

Simply add the `DllImport` native function signature:

```
 [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
 static extern IntPtr FindFirstFile
     (string lpFileName, out WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData);
```

and CLR will do managed to native type marshaling automatically.

**[Edit]** I just realized you're using C++/CLI. In that case, you can also use [implicit P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x8kf7zx.aspx), which is a feature which only C++ supports (opposed to C# and VB.NET). This articles shows several examples:

[How to: Convert Between Various String Types in C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that

```
String^ str = "C:\\my.dll";

::LoadLibraryEx(LPCWSTR)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(str).ToPointer(), 0, flags);
```

does not work, returning code 87.  Instead,

```
#include <atlstr.h>

CString s("C:\\my.dll");
::LoadLibraryEx((LPCWSTR)s, 0, flags);
```

has been working like a charm and seems to be the least verbose method.