# Is it possible to get a pointer to String^'s internal array in C++/CLI?

Tags: string, c++-cli, wchar-t

The goal is to avoid copying the string data when I need a `const wchar_t*`.

The answer seems to be yes, but the function [`PtrToStringChars`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062962/systemstring-to-lpcwstr/1063154#1063154) doesn't have its own MSDN entry (it's only mentioned in the KB and blogs as a trick). That made me suspicious and I want to check with you guys. Is it safe to use that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, no problem.  It is actually somewhat [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1ae6tz5%28VS.80%29.aspx) but hard to find.  The MSDN docs for the C++ libraries aren't great.  It returns an interior pointer, that's not suitable for conversion to a const wchar_t* yet.  You have to pin the pointer so the garbage collector cannot move the string.  Use pin_ptr<> to do that.

You can use Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni() to create a copy of the string.  Use that instead if the wchar_t* needs to stay valid for an extended period of time.  Pinning objects too long isn't very healthy for the garbage collector.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `StringToHGlobalUni`.  Using `PtrToStringChars` and then making a copy yourself could be quite a bit faster than messing with HGLOBAL, which is a specialized allocator with limited practical use.  Actually `marshal_as<BSTR>` or `marshal_as<std::wstring>` would be by recommendations for a native copy.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Here is a complete solution based on PtrToStringChars that accesses the managed string internals and then copies the contents using standard C functions:

```
wchar_t *ManagedStringToUnicodeString(String ^s)
{
    // Declare
    wchar_t *ReturnString = nullptr;
    long len = s->Length;

    // Check length
    if(len == 0) return nullptr;

    // Pin the string
    pin_ptr<const wchar_t> PinnedString = PtrToStringChars(s);

    // Copy to new string
    ReturnString = (wchar_t *)malloc((len+1)*sizeof(wchar_t));
    if(ReturnString)
    {
        wcsncpy(ReturnString, (wchar_t *)PinnedString, len+1);
    }

    // Unpin
    PinnedString = nullptr;

    // Return
    return ReturnString;
}
```