# How do i play a sound file whare the file name is from a system string

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

```
String ^ fileName = textBox5->Text + "DES.wav";

PlaySound(fileName, NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_SYNC);
```

The error is saying:

Error   4   error C2664: 'PlaySoundW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::String ^' to 'LPCWSTR'

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062962/systemstring-to-lpcwstr

Comment: This is an exact dupe of that question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to mix managed and unmanaged code, use `SoundPlayer` class:

```
String ^ fileName = textBox5->Text + "DES.wav";
SoundPlayer^ player = gcnew SoundPlayer(filename);
player->PlaySync();    // or Play for asynchronous execution
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx

Comment: I tried this code with all the valid include statements and used the necessary namespaces but i get a runime error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. I even tried triming my file name to remove leading and trailing white spaces

Additional information: Illegal characters in path.

Comment: What line throws exception? What is the value of filename variable? Does such file exist? Debug it and provide more information.

Comment: I can type the file name in as a string "wordDES.wav" and it plays the sound. But when ever i try to concat the word (which varies at run time) the exception occurs.A first chance exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Illegal characters in path.

Comment: What is the value of textbox? What is the value of fileName variable? Use debugger. This code prints `wordDES.wav` in my test: `String ^ fileName = "word" + "DES.wav"; Console::WriteLine(fileName);`

Comment: I figured out my error. When i was getting a string from another textbox and setting it in text box 5, i forgot to trim it so it had some leading characters that wasn't being shown and affected the playsound function. Thanks for the help! :)