# Converting from C# string to C++ wchar_t [unmanaged]

Tags: c#, c++, windows-runtime

I'm working on a WinRT app in which I need to pass Device ID from C# class to C++ object. The format of ID is:

```
\\?\SWD#MMDEVAPI#{0.0.0.00000000}.{572cb138-dda1-4723-90d7-373f04b795fb}#{e6327cad-dcec-4949-ae8a-991e976a79d2}
```

This works well in C++ if I cast it as:

```
L"\\\\?\\SWD#MMDEVAPI#{0.0.0.00000000}.{572cb138-dda1-4723-90d7-373f04b795fb}#{e6327cad-dcec-4949-ae8a-991e976a79d2}"
```

However, if I pass it as [System.String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) from C# class to C++ and cast it as LPCWSTR, it doesn't work.

**C++ code:**

```
UniversalAudioPlayer::UniversalAudioPlayer(String^ deviceID)
{
HRESULT hr = XAudio2Create(&xAudio);

if (FAILED(hr))
    ref new COMException(hr, "XAudio2Create failure");

XAUDIO2_DEBUG_CONFIGURATION debugConfig = { 0 };
debugConfig.TraceMask = XAUDIO2_LOG_DETAIL | XAUDIO2_LOG_WARNINGS;
xAudio->SetDebugConfiguration(&debugConfig);

hr = xAudio->CreateMasteringVoice(&masteringVoice, 0U, 0U, 0U, (LPCWSTR)deviceID);

if (FAILED(hr))
    ref new COMException(hr, "Could not create mastdsdering voice");

xAudio->StartEngine();
}
```

**C# code:**

```
UniversalAudioPlayer player = new UniversalAudioPlayer("\\\\?\\SWD#MMDEVAPI#{0.0.0.00000000}.{41a5b8e4-ad46-4bcb-b8a0-3621edafd176}#{e6327cad-dcec-4949-ae8a-991e976a79d2}");
```

**I'm not able to include**

```
#include < vcclr.h >
```

in my C++ class either as WinRT doesn't support managed assemblies.

Please suggest me any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Theres an [MSDN code example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/d1ae6tz5(v=vs.100).aspx) for it.

Comment: I tried it already. I can't include <vcclr.h>.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062962/systemstring-to-lpcwstr May be relevant. Please add your code so it's more clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @WiredPrairie https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh405048(v=vs.85).aspx this is the method I want to pass szDeviceId to, from my C# class.

Comment: OK -- and what code did you write that isn't working? How are you trying to convert from one string to another? Are you using pinning, `Marshal`, etc?

Comment: I edited my post and added both C++ and C# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert from a [Platform::String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh755812.aspx)^ to a wchar_t* with the String::[Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825860.aspx) method.

```
hr = xAudio->CreateMasteringVoice(&masteringVoice, 0U, 0U, 0U, deviceID->Data);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Never imagined the solution was that simple. Saved me from a big trouble.